# SharePoint 2007 Form auto submit

Tags: 2007, list-form

I would like to use standard SharePoint form for list (NewForm.aspx), but want to auto submit it after specified time - 60 minutes to list. All fields will be optional. This will be used for quiz for users.

Is there a way how to simply insert a piece of script into NewForm.aspx source to do this? Or with use of customized form instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would *want* to do this but... you could probably accomplish this with a little JavaScript on the page.

My JavaScript library of choice is Prototype.js so you can find the OK buttons with a selector like:

```
input[id$="diidIOSaveItem"]
```

Then, it is just a matter of "clicking" them after an hour (60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 = 3,600,000 ms):

```
function SubmitFormAfterAnHour() {
    $$('input[id$="diidIOSaveItem"]').each(function(elem){
        elem.onclick();
    });
}
setTimeout("SubmitFormAfterAnHour()", 3600000);
```

(I am typing this in Notepad so please test)

Comment: Thank you Kit, this works for me.

Reason why is, that my team wants to provide any quiz attendees only specific timeframe for quiz.

Thanks again,
m.

Comment: this would be ideal for a quiz I have as well, can you tell me where I would put the script?
Kris

Comment: @Kris There are a couple different ways which I've documented here: http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation&referringTitle=Documentation